# Visited Calendar Doesn't Render

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, visited-days, calendar

When when I'm looking at my [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153393/zeke) and click on the "visited 26 days, 19 consecutive" link, no calendar pops up. The calendar seems to appear for an instant (sometimes) but then disappears without really affecting the page formatting (i.e., no big gap where a calendar should be appears). This just started happening today (I was active yesterday and there was no problem), and happens for all my SE accounts (SO, Meta, Programmers).

Comment: Repro in Chrome 9 (yeah, yeah), Firefox 3.6.10, Firefox 3.6.12, and IE8 (doesn't even come up at all in IE8).

Comment: Since you specify Chrome, did you try other browsers and it was only Chrome that was broken?  Seems broken "across the board* for me.

Comment: Since I can repro on other browsers as well, I've taken the liberty and edited out mentions of Chrome.

Comment: @waiwai: Thanks. @Rebecca: I didn't check with any other browsers, only my primary browser (Chrome). You're right, this isn't a very thorough bug report; I'll check with other browsers next time before reporting.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same. IE 8 and Firefox 3.6.12.

Comment: @waiwai933, thanks.  Didn't want to edit it out without confirmation from someone else.

Comment: Repro in FF 3.6.12 -- it pops up, and then immediately disappears. I see a flash of the Ajax spinner and the bright green calendar boxes.

Comment: Repro in Opera 10.63, behaviour just like Jon Siegel wrote about FF. It works only once then link is dead. Refresh page gives a new chance.

Comment: This is tagged "status-completed," but the problem is still happening? There is also this error in the console now: `Uncaught TypeError: $cal.datepicker is not a function`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) stylesheet changed, making the main `.ui-datepicker` be hidden - a fix will be pushed in the next build.