# No styles on programmers.se

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At the time of this writing, there are no styles on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) (or its meta site). Tried with multiple browsers on multiple computers.

Edit:

This seems to be the case on all beta sites.

Comment: Reproduced, two different browsers.

Comment: Not just Programmers.  Seems to be any beta site from the ones I've spot-checked.

Comment: @waiwai933: I would have posted it here if Tim hadn't. I don't imagine there is anyone at StackOverflow headquarters checking *each and every meta-site* periodically to make sure things are OK. This is the appropriate place to post serious site problems happening on any SE site.

Comment: @waiwai933 - Questions (or bug reports) that should immediately be noticed by the SE developers _are_ appropriate here.

Comment: ...and regardless, this isn't something that affects only 1 site.

Comment: @Robert I'm withdrawing my comment because Rebecca pointed out that this situation applies to all beta sites. However, the SE team does monitor all meta sites routinely and has mentioned that many times previously.

Comment: @waiwai933: It's difficult to report this on meta.programmers when meta.programmers is also not working.

Comment: @Robert Considering the OP was able to do so, I don't think it presents much of a problem.

Comment: @waiwai: Do you have a link for one of the many times the SO team has said they monitor all meta sites?

Comment: money.stackexchange.com and meta.money.stackexchange.com are both broken.

Comment: @Robert I can't find it right now (all my Google searches are turning up the community problem at meta.math), but I remember there being one where someone asked for a feature on MSO, where Jeff or Robert (can't remember which) said so.

Comment: Repped 3781 -> 3491

Answer (score 4):

Recently we migrated to a new css framework (lesscss) we are still sorting out some kinks, should be fixed now

Comment: Programmers.Meta is still down.

Comment: @Robert .... fixed

Answer (score 0):

The Artificial Intelligence (private) beta is working fine at this time. Programmers is currently broke. I think this is related to the [days visited calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/visited-calendar-doesnt-render) being broken on all sites.

Comment: Artificial Intelligence is fine, Programmers are broke. Coincidence?!? ;]

Comment: It sounds like the way my boss wants things to be. :(