# Visited calendar on profile page shows for fraction of a second and gets hidden

Tags: bug, profile-page, visited-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visited Calendar Doesn't Render](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/visited-calendar-doesnt-render)

Steps to repro:

- Visit your profile page, click on days visited

Expected:

- Calendar shows with dates visited highlighted in green

Actual Results:

- Calendar shows for fraction of a second and gets hidden

Browsers affected:

- IE 8, Firefox 3.6.12

(Also Chrome 9 dev, but you guys don't consider it so mentioning as separate point)

Comment: I want to say repro, but I didn't even get to see it before it got hidden. I did see the loading graphic, though.

Comment: @GraceNote Firefox seems to show for a fraction longer than most browsers.

Comment: @Rebecca Nooooooooooooooooo it didn't show up in related :(

Comment: that is no excuse. q:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff :( /voted to close anyway