# Consecutive days calendar not working

Tags: bug, google-chrome, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visited Calendar Doesn't Render](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/visited-calendar-doesnt-render)

When I click the consecutive days link, the calendar expands, then collapses again, and then I cannot click it anymore.

It happens on every site, and I'm using Chrome (yes, the beta 8.0.552.215 version, and although *betas are not supported ZOMG!!11!!1one!* I wonder if it happens to anyone in the stable version as well, or if it can happen when the current version goes out of beta).

Comment: Sorry Juan, but it's already reported over at [Visited Calendar Doesn't Render](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/visited-calendar-doesnt-render). The good news is, a fix is in the works and should be in the next deployment.